# oracle sqldeveloper does not show object counts

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there a way when you select several objects [Tables] from the connection tree/schema browser on the sqldevelpper, show the number of objects being selected.

Answer (score 0):

No.

But it should, so I have logged an enhancement request (28094063)

Comment: Can't believe my luck !!! Got the note from the legend Jeff Smith. Thank you Sir and You made my day.